# Как быть, если параметр к методу String и этот String должен содержать ""?

Tags: c#, selenium

Ищу в Selenium элемент по XPath, но в самом XPath имеются " и язык считывает, что строка заканчивается. Как быть? 
`Elem.FindElemByXPath("//*[@id="userbar"]//*[@class="auth-bar‌​__item auth-bar__item--text"]");`

Comment: например экранировать кавычки

Comment: Добавь пример непосредственно в вопрос. Для редактирования используй кнопку [edit] под вопросом

Comment: Это не студия считает, а стандарт языка. Вы бы перед тем как ругать идиотов из Майкрософт почитали документацию.

Comment: @VladD я не ругаюсь, я спрашиваю что в данной ситуации делать.

Comment: @VladD, не поищешь дубликат, мне кажется уже попадались вопросы про экранирования?

Comment: @Grundy: Не нашлось :-\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для экранирования кавычек в строке, в данном случае можно использовать обратный слэш: `\`

```
Elem.FindElemByXPath("//*[@id=\"userbar\"]//*[@class=\"auth-bar‌​__item auth-bar__item--text\"]")
```

Если бы использовался символ `@` перед строкой, то для экранирования кавычек их нужно удваивать:

```
Elem.FindElemByXPath(@"//*[@id=""userbar""]//*[@class=""auth-bar‌​__item auth-bar__item--text""]")
```

Comment: спасибо большое.